# Having an issue with NX 3.5.0 and SSH during user authentication phase (time out)

Tags: linux, ssh, authentication, nx-server

SuSE SLES 11 SP3 Intel P4

I've installed NX 3.5.0 from NoMachines on my home server which has been working quite well until recently when I change the Domain Name for my server through my registrar which inadvertently broke authentication on the system by invalidating the SSL Cert for openLDAP. I have a openLDAP setup as my back-end for Linux authentications. I have disabled SSL both for openLDAP server and LDAP client libraries as all connections will be local and avoid the overhead. Now I authenticate quite well now. Although that resolve that particular problem, I continue to having an issue with NX Client authenticating, I keep getting this error:

```
NX> 500 ERROR: Operation timeout in communication with SSH server
```

On further investigation, server logs indicate:

```
Sep 14 05:07:43 home NXSERVER-3.5.0-11[27342]: ERROR: reached timeout of 20s while trying SSHd authentication for user '*************', to '127.0.0.1', port '22' 'NXNssUserManager::auth'
```

Steps taken attempting to resolve this issue. I went thought NoMachine documentation and I could not discover any information regarding how to increase the timeout value. Alternatively. I decided that I should try to shorten SSH login delay. This is basically were I am stuck for the past few days, during some test:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8j-fips 07 Jan 2009
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to localhost [::1] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: identity file /home/***********/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/***********/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/***********/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/***********/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /home/***********/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: identity file /home/***********/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.2
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.2 pat OpenSSH*
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: server->client aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: kex: client->server aes128-ctr hmac-md5-etm@openssh.com none
debug1: sending SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ECDSA 46:0f:51:88:c1:55:6f:c0:15:9e:5c:08:57:cc:5a:d9 [MD5]
debug1: Host 'localhost' is known and matches the ECDSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/lutchy.horace/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug1: ssh_ecdsa_verify: signature correct
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: Roaming not allowed by server
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_REQUEST sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,keyboard-interactive
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/***********/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/***********/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/***********/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Next authentication method: keyboard-interactive
....
```

There is a 20 second delay for the server to respond with a prompt. One the server side:

```
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug1: userauth-request for user ******** service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug2: input_userauth_request: try method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug1: auth2_challenge: user=******** devs= [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam' [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug2: auth2_challenge_start: devices pam [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug2: kbdint_next_device: devices <empty> [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug1: auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam' [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_sshpam_init_ctx [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 104 [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_sshpam_init_ctx: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PAM_INIT_CTX [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 105 [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 104
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_answer_pam_init_ctx
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_init_ctx entering
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 105
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_sshpam_query [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 106 [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_sshpam_query: waiting for MONITOR_ANS_PAM_QUERY [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_receive_expect entering: type 107 [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_receive entering
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: monitor_read: checking request 106
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_answer_pam_query
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_query entering
Sep 14 05:29:14 home sshd[27452]: debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
...
```

20 second delay:

```
Sep 14 05:29:34 home sshd[27454]: debug3: PAM: sshpam_thread_conv entering, 1 messages
Sep 14 05:29:34 home sshd[27454]: debug3: ssh_msg_send: type 1
Sep 14 05:29:34 home sshd[27454]: debug3: ssh_msg_recv entering
Sep 14 05:29:34 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_request_send entering: type 107
Sep 14 05:29:34 home sshd[27452]: debug3: mm_sshpam_query: pam_query returned 0 [preauth]
Sep 14 05:29:34 home sshd[27452]: Postponed keyboard-interactive for ********* from ::1 port 55653 ssh2 [preauth].
```

I've already followed common threads for SSH Login delays, none have provided any solutions to rectify the problem. I can only deduced that SSH is probably waiting for a response from PAM (PAM: sshpam_thread_conv)? NSCD is running and is caching passwd. For the life me, I can't tell well the delay might be in terms of PAM and pam_ldap.so. Any assistance would be helpful.

P.S. I don't have any complicated PAM setup, 'pam_unix then pam_ldap'

Comment: Hi and Welcome to SU. Thanks for taking the time to explain how you solved it but please don't mark questions as `[SOLVED]`. Instead, post an answer explaining what you did and accept it (you also get a nice [rep](http://superuser.com/privileges) boost).

Comment: Already, I am new here so I'll keep that in mind in the future. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Luckily, after several hours of toying with this issues I was able to resolve this nasty problem. It appears that the hostname of the system is intertwined into everything you do in Linux and it appears prior to the `ldap` client libraries connecting to the server, it does a forward lookup on the server hostname.

I did some TCPDUMP and it looks like the DNS server was returning a Format error because the query string was invalid. It looks like Linux doesn't play nice with hostnames with several sub domains, ie `home.s2.lhprojects.net`, instead is was doing a forward lookup on `home. lhprojects.net` An odd behavior but I am sure there is a really good reason for that.

Simply adding `127.0.0.1 home.s2.lhprojects.net` to `/etc/hosts` solved it. Thanks anyway all.